# SQL Need to select rows that don't have same spelling or don't match joined from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to return columns that don't have the same names in each row or don't match in SQL. I have tried finding things but I can't find the right solutions because anything similar is looking for results that don't match from the same table.

For example here is what I would be working with.

| table1.ID | table1.name | table2.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IL | Nina | Niña |
| IL | Mike | Mike |
| WI | Jon | Jonn |
| AZ | Eric | Eric |
| AZ | Alex | NULL |
| TX | NULL | Tom |
| TX | Ian | Ian |

I would want to return the Nina's that are spelled different, the Jon's, the Alex with Null, and Null/Tom

In MySQL

Comment: I don't think I understand, why can't you just use `WHERE table1.name <> table2.name?`

Comment: I tried, It returns nothing.

Comment: And I know that the two tables have different counts because when I count distinct and take the difference, it has more distinct values in table 1 than table 2.

Comment: Are you not joining the two tables? If not then have you tried `SELECT table1.ID, table1.name from table1 WHERE table1.name NOT IN (SELECT table2.name from table2)`? You can can then union on the same query but in reverse to get all the differences between the tables. If you're wanting it to be differences on the same line then you'll have to do what Aadmaa has answered.

Comment: When you say 'row', do you mean 'column'?

Comment: alex with a null is impossible

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like SOUNDEX(expr) or SOUNDS LIKE. You'll want to index on that.

It will be something like this:

```
select A.id, A.name as A_name, B.name as B_name
from table1 as A
inner join table2 as B 
on A.name SOUNDS LIKE B.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @table1 as table(ID varchar(2), name varchar(20))
 declare @table2 as table(name varchar(20))

 insert into @table1(ID,name) values('IL','Nina') ,('IL','Mike'),('WI','Jon')   
 ,('AZ','Eric'),('AZ','Alex'),('TX',NULL),('TX','Ian')  

 insert into @table2(name) values('Niña'),('Mike'),('Jonn'),('Eric'), (NULL),('Tom'),('Ian')

 select tb1.ID,tb1.name,tb2.name name_tb2 from @table1 tb1 right join @table2 tb2
 on soundex(tb1.name) like soundex(tb2.name)
```

output

```
 ID     name    name_tb2
 NULL   NULL    Niña
 IL     Mike    Mike
 WI     Jon     Jonn
 AZ     Eric    Eric
 NULL   NULL    NULL
 NULL   NULL    Tom
 TX     Ian     Ian
```